# Value from Select tag shows blank on PHP variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I've got this form up in a site. I can't get the value from the select tag to get collected by a variable on the php. No matter what option gets selected, it shows blank in the PHP.

Every other input value gets accurately collected by it's php variable.

I believe i checked enough for typos, unclosed tags or missing characters. Would it be some sort of rule about < select > tags that i'm not aware of?

The HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <label id="sendtolabel"><span>Send To:</span></label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option> 
        </select>
        <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">Name</span></label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" title="name" />
        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">Email</span></label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" title="email" />
        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">Comments</span></label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" title="comments"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
     </fieldset>
  </form>
```

The PHP

```
$select = $_POST['select']; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$comments = $_POST['comments']
```

Comment: First of all, try calling the <select> something other than "select", since "select" is a reserved HTML keyword, and possibly the reason you're having trouble. Note that I'm referring to `name="select"`.

Comment: Tried something else and still didn't work. Thanks for the answer, tho.

Comment: I checked ..It works for me.

Comment: I checked its working fine. what version of PHP you are using.

Comment: just debug var_dump($_POST), see what did you get

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.3.6

Answer (score 3):

It's Working Here... You can try this:

```
<?php
   if ( isset( $_POST['select'] ) ) {
       var_dump( $_POST['select'] );
       $select = $_POST['select']; 
       $name = $_POST['name']; 
       $email = $_POST['email']; 
       $comments = $_POST['comments'];
       echo "THE SELECT VAR's Value is: __".$select;
   }
?>
<form method="post" action="" name="contactform" id="contactform" autocomplete="off">
   <fieldset>
        <label id="sendtolabel"><span>Send To:</span></label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option> 
        </select>
        <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">Name</span></label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" title="name" />
        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">Email</span></label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" title="email" />
        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">Comments</span></label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" title="comments"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>
```

> NOTE: You can Test the code above in a phpfiddle.
>
> 1) Go to http://phpfiddle.org/
>   2) Paste the Code in the **`Editor`** then
>   press Run[F9]

*Click here to test the Code in fiddle*: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tuc-6jm

Comment: Notice the added `echo` and the `if (isset($_POST['select']))`.. helps you run the code only when necessary and avoid `Undefined Variable` errors

Comment: Doesn't output anything while echoing inside the if.. adding an else echoing the same thing just outputs the text while the $select doesn't  add anything to the string.

Comment: It works PERFECTLY here... may be you have some other issues. Is the PHP code in the same page as the HTML?.. iF Yes use the code above as it is. If NO, do something like `action="pageToPhpCodes.php"`

Answer (score 0):

When i have a problem like that, i just print all the $_POST global to see what has been returned

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And nope.. your code is correct

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <form method="post" action="test.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" autocomplete="off">
          <fieldset>
          <label id="sendtolabel"><span>Send To:</span></label>
          <select name="select" id="select">
              <option value="1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              <option value="4">Option 4</option> 
          </select>
          <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">Name</span></label>
          <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" title="name" />
          <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">Email</span></label>
          <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" title="email" />
          <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">Comments</span></label>
          <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" title="comments"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
         </fieldset>
     </form>
<?php 

   print_r( $_POST );
   echo $_POST['select'];
   $select = $_POST['select']; 
   $name = $_POST['name']; 
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
   $comments = $_POST['comments'];
   echo $select;
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

select is returning what it has to return... (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: It outputs: Array ( [name] => name [email] => email [comments] => comments )... Looks like it's completely ignoring the $select variable

Comment: Are you shure that that is the complete code? because everybody here agrees that the code you just posted is working fine..maybe you are unsetting that variable..

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me.

Just try in this way. Put this code on top of contact.php to test whether all values are retrieving properly or not.

```
<?php
    if ( $_POST ) {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r( $_POST );
       die;
    }
?>
```

See the out put below: http://d.pr/i/dgN3